# Sending sms to multiple phone numbers with Laravel Notifications

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm developing a web site and would like to send a sms message to multiple phone numbers with Nexmo, using Laravel 5.4.

My application has a one-to-many relationship between a `User` (Notifiable) and `PhoneNumber` model. The latter has `user_id` and `number` fields.

I'd like to use the elegant Notifications system Laravel offers and just be able to send a message to ALL of a given user's phone numbers by doing `$user->notify(new FooNotification())`.

I have tried routing the notification by adding a `routeNotificationForNexmo` function to my `User` model and returning the phone numbers as an array of strings, but as expected that returns an error ('array to string conversion').

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Edit: for now, I've made PhoneNumber implement `Notifiable` as well, then I'll just have to invoke `notify()` for each of a user's phone numbers... I'm still hoping for a better solution though.

Comment: how are you returning the numbers , post your code

Comment: @Rahul As I said, I'm returning them as an array of strings.

Comment: so in view you get this error ('array to string conversion').

Comment: I never tried this for nexmo. but for sending email to many you cannot use `$user->notify(new EmailNotification)` but instead you can use notification facade like `Notification:send($user->emails, new EmailNotification)` . Since you have the data, you can try it easily. see if it works

Comment: @PeymanSeraj Thanks for your suggestion. I'm afraid that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add the `Notifiable` trait to your `PhoneNumber` model. (I see you've already done this)
2. Add the `routeNotificationForNexmo` function to the `PhoneNumber` model.
3. Use the Notification facade like so: `Notification::send($user->numbers, new FooNotification)`

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, and I'm not very satisfied with this option. Having the `Notifiable` trait on the `PhoneNumber` model feels very awkward.

Comment: It does solve the question/problem though yes? I think it will help to keep in mind that logically Laravel Notifications is for information to send across multiple channels, because you are not fussy about which channel reaches the user. If the solution seems messy to you best is to switch the functionality to your own custom sms service that handles multiple valid phone numbers for one user.